# Should an answer contain links to other questions on this site as a Further reading or See also

Tags: discussion

The answer to the question [Did/does the US government keep secret papers by Nikola Tesla?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14513/did-does-the-us-government-keep-secret-papers-by-nikola-tesla) contains mentioning of the HAARP as a possible result for research taken from Tesla, and notes that there are conspiracy theories that involve it.

As Oddthinking noted, there is a question about HAARP already in the site:
[Can HAARP affect weather or earthquakes?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/979/can-haarp-affect-weather-or-earthquakes/1014#1014) Should the answer include a link to the question as a "further reading" or a "see also" part, like in wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? If you are not changing the meaning of the question and you are not putting a major eye-sore banner in, I don't see what the problem is.

If you have edit privileges, we trust you to improve any posts :-)

> ## When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - **to add related resources or hyperlinks**
>
> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

—[Privileges - Edit questions and answers](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Oops. I can see some of the confusion could have been avoided by me directly editing the question to include a link to the other HAARP question.

I actually intended to do one better than that. I tried to edit some of the previous questions that addressed HAARP with a [haarp](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haarp). However, I was using a mobile device at the time, and discovered you may not add novel tags from a mobile device. I didn't have time to edit it in full, so I put a quick comment in instead.

Given the confusion it caused both the OP and Ilya, I regret taking a shortcut. Sorry.